# Why can't I get the postgresql server to run?

Tags: ruby, macos, bash, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Ok. I have been trying to solve this problem for several days. I installed, uninstalled, and reinstalled Postgresql 3 times. I followed precisely the instructions in this forum: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42048/cant-connect-to-the-postgres-server-ls-tmp-s-pgsql-5432-no-such-file-or-dir

I found this solution in many forums, so I tried to run:

```
$ mkdir /var/pgsql_socket/
$ sudo mkdir /var/pgsql_socket/
$ ln -s /private/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/pgsql_socket/
```

But this didn't work. When I try to start the server it still says there is another one running and then proceeds to fail every time I try to create a database or type "psql"

I then tried to run the following in order to change the path of the commands from OS X's builtin version of postgres to my version and it seemed to work:

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin
$ rm postgres
$ ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/postgres postgres
$ rm psql
$ ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/psql psql
$ rm pg_ctl
$ ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/pg_ctl pg_ctl
```

So then I ran the following to create a user for postgres:

```
$ sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser $Sarah
$ sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser user_sarah
$ sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

But it kept saying "unknown user postgres"
I then tried to install the Ruby pg gem, but that also failed, saying there was a problem with necessary libraries.

I have saved a text file of everything I tried to do in the terminal. Let me know if I should post that. Thanks.

**update:**
When I try to run this:
`$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start`
I get this:
`-bash: /usr/local/bin/pg_ctl: No such file or directory`
Which is different from a lot of other errors that I have seen posted on this problem.

Comment: does a `postgres` account exist on the computer? I'm guessing not, since it's saying unknown user...

Comment: So that is something different than what I tried to do with `createuser`? If so then no. I tried to do it a different way I found and it gave me this error `createuser: creation of new role failed: ERROR:  role "Sarah" already exists`

Comment: Start with where you downloaded pg from, which will tell what install instructions apply

Comment: I ran `brew install postgres`

Answer (score 1):

first, you should verify that there is no postmaster running: ps -ef | grep postmaster.  once you've verified the postmaster is not running, you should look into the postgresql command initd.  Depending on your server installation, it may or may not be installed.  You need to create a database before attempting to start postgres.  It sounds to me like you got an installation that didn't install the main postgresql commands to /usr/bin, pg_ctl being one of these.

FYI: the postgres account is not a login account and is automatically created when installing postgresql, so it should be there if you had a good installation.  You cannot sudo as postgres if postgres is not in the sudoers file.

Comment: what is the problem with postmaster running?

Comment: In general, I don't like to run initd on postgres if the postmaster is already running.  Offhand, I don't know how it will react.

Answer (score 1):

The homebrew install of PostgreSQL does not create or need a `postgres` account, so all the mentions of doing `sudo -u postgres`or `ps -fu postgres` don't apply to your case.

The command `brew info postgresql` outputs various information about to start and stop it, you may read them. By contrast you don't want to put blind faith into what random users tell about how they "fixed" their non-working installation. In fact, the web carries a shocking amount of bad advice concerning PostgreSQL on MacOS X, and to me the answer you linked on dba.se is among them. It's wrong from start to finish, and you should note that it was not accepted as an answer. Certainly the author means well, but he fails to see that his own context can't be generalized to other installations.

The worst part is the suggestion to delete in `/usr/local/bin/` the binaries `postgres`, `psql`, `pg_ctl` and soft-linking them into supposed equivalents inside `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/`.
To me it just breaks the homebrew install.
No wonder that after doing this you get this error:

> /usr/local/bin/pg_ctl: No such file or directory

So my answer would be to reinstall postgresql with brew to restart from a clean state, then make sure that all postgres commands you launch are from `/usr/local/bin`, and always first read the server log file passed to `pg_ctl` if you have any doubt on anything PG-related.